# Interactive/Dynamic plotting in R - Histogram as data is sampled

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I am working with Sequential Monte Carlo, and I would like to visualize how the data I am working with is distributed as it is being sampled. Therefore, I thought about creating a dynamic/interactive plot, to illustrate the development of the sampled data.

I have tried to look at the first search matches on Google, but at a first glance, they do not do what I intend to do. 
Instead, I thought about writing a for-loop with delays in it, but that is what I would expect from some already existing package including some repeat mechanism.

I thought that there must be someone out there, who had thought about creating the same interactive plot which eases the understanding of how the method employed works.

To sum it up with a few words, I would like to get a histogram of `X_t` as `t` progresses.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `shiny` package which allows you to make small webapps. I built a few apps for teaching monte-carlo simulation. One [app](https://fhsg.shinyapps.io/newsboy/) about the famous newsboy-model features this kind of histogram.

The code for the newsboy-model app (containing a histogram):

server.R

```
library(ggplot2)

function(input, output, session) {
  output$demand <- renderPlot({
    set.seed(1)
    values <- round(runif(input$nr_of_runs, min(input$demand_range), max(input$demand_range)))
    demand <- as.data.frame(values)
    ggplot(demand, aes(x = values)) +
      geom_histogram(aes(y= ..count..), binwidth = 1, col = I("white"), fill = "forestgreen") +
      xlim(c(0,200)) + xlab("No. of newspapers demanded") +
      ylab("Counts") +
      ggtitle("Probability-Distribution of Demand") +
      theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15, colour = "forestgreen"),
                              axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, colour = "forestgreen"),
                              axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
                              axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
                              plot.title = element_text(size = 20))
  })

  output$sales <- renderPlot({
    set.seed(1)
    values <- round(runif(input$nr_of_runs, min(input$demand_range), max(input$demand_range)))
    demand <- as.data.frame(values)

    profit <- data.frame(nr_of_newspapers_bought = numeric(200), mean_profit = numeric(200))
    prize_buy <- min(input$prize)
    prize_sell <- max(input$prize)
    for(bought in 1:200) {
      sold <- pmin(bought, demand$values)
      profits <- sold*prize_sell - bought*prize_buy
      profit$nr_of_newspapers_bought[bought] <- bought
      profit$mean_profit[bought] <- mean(profits)
    }
    ggplot(profit, aes(nr_of_newspapers_bought)) + geom_line(aes(y = mean_profit)) +
      xlim(c(0,200)) + ggtitle("Profit depending on newspapers sold") +
      xlab("No. of newspapers sold") + ylab("Mean profit")  +
      theme_classic() + theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
                              axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
                              plot.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = which.max(mean_profit)), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = max(mean_profit)), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
      annotate("text", label = which.max(profit$mean_profit), x = 7 + which.max(profit$mean_profit),
               y = 10 + min(profit$mean_profit), size = 8, colour = "red") +
      annotate("text", label = round(max(profit$mean_profit),2), x = 0,
               y = max(profit$mean_profit) - 0.1*(max(profit$mean_profit) - min(profit$mean_profit)),
               size = 8, colour = "red")
  })

}
```

ui.R

```
fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Newsboy Model with Monte Carlo Simulation'),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput('nr_of_runs', 'Nr of runs', 1,
                 min = 1, max = 10000, step = 1, animate = TRUE),
    sliderInput('prize', 'Prize (buy and sell)', c(1, 1.5),
                min = 0, max = 10, step = 0.1),
    sliderInput('demand_range', 'Demand Range (min and max)', c(100, 190), min = 0, max = 200)
    ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('demand'),
    plotOutput('sales')
  )
)
```

The following Single-file shiny app produces random data and then adds it to the histogram with increasing number of runs.

```
# sample data outside loop because of reactivity
n <- 1000
data <- runif(n)


# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  sliderInput('nr_of_samples', 'Nr of samples', 1,
              min = 1, max = n, step = 1, animate = TRUE),
  plotOutput('hist')
)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(data[1:input$nr_of_samples], breaks = 5, xlim = c(0,1))
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! How do a get a plot to show up?
When I run your code as 'server' and 'ui' respectively, and launch through ShinyApp I get a server page with interactive sliders but no plot?

Comment: Save both files as `ui.R` and `server.R?` respectively. Then launch the app by pressing the `run app` button in R Studio. That works for me.

Comment: I got it to work, and it looks quite nice.
I'll work with it tomorrow and revert if needed.
Thank you!

Comment: Of cause, but I would like to explore it in dept before I determine if it solved my issue.